# Shot the percentage of column for particular date

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
ID | OS      | sold | Date
---+---------+------+-----
 1 | ios     |  1   | 5/1
 2 | ios     |  1   | 5/1
 3 | android |  2   | 5/1
 4 | android |  2   | 5/1
 5 | ios     |  1   | 5/2
```

And I want to show the percentage of the total sold in May that was occurred on 5/2.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you represent the date, but it would be something like:

```
select sum(case when date = '2020-05-01' then sold else 0 end) * 1.0 / sum(sold)
from t;
```

Comment: hi, so I make a similar case but I got 0. could you take a look ? http://tpcg.io/B1jc9fd8

Comment: @dadfsf . . . SQLite (which your question does NOT have as a tag) does integer division, so `1/2 = 0`, not `0.5`.

Comment: Isn't sqlite uses SQL? I run it https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-sql-online/v here and game result. How do I fix it?

Comment: @dadfsf . . . SQLite is a *database*.  SQL is a language.  SQLite implements are dialect of SQL and pretty much all dialects have their own peculiarities.

Comment: oh I see could you explain the part where ```then sold else 0 end``` ?

Comment: @dadfsf . . . That sums the sales on the date in question.